# Except (^ or _dvl) analog in k4, 8 Queens example

Tags: kdb, k

I've just played with 8 Queens puzzle, and found out that it seems there is no `_dvl` operator (from `k(v2)`) in `k(v4)`. Also I checked other `k` versions from *ngn* [k impls](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k.html) and found `^` operator in `k(v6)`, for example at [JohnEarnest's impl](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok/blob/gh-pages/docs/Manual.md#null):

> l^a or l^l is except. Remove all instances of each of y from x.
>
> ```
> k) 1 3 2 5 1 2 3^1 3 5
> 2 2
> ```

I really love SQL-style and would like to apply it in `q`. But is the following way idiomatic in `q/k(v4)` and is it a good solution? Or maybe there are **shorter ways** to do such **list comparison/exclusion** exists:

```
q)show s:til 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
q)s where not s in 2 4 6 /bother about this line, can it be shorter?
0 1 3 5 7
```

---

My version of `q8` code is a bit longer then in *nsl* [k2](http://www.nsl.com/k/qn.k), without recursion and without conditions:

```
f:{raze {(x,) each (til 8) where not (til 8) in {x,(x-f),x+f:reverse 1+til count x} x} each x}
\ts:10 7 f/til 8 /248 100128
count  7 f/til 8 /92
first  7 f/til 8 /0 4 7 5 2 6 1 3
```

**Upd:** command I was looking for is **except**:

```
q)f:{raze {(x,) each (til 8) except {x,(x-f),x+f:reverse 1+til count x} x} each x}
```

**Upd2:** generalized 8 Queens solution in `k(v4)`:

```
k){(x-1){,/{(x,)'(!y)@&~(!y)in{x,(x-f),x+f:|1+!#x}x}[;y]'x}[;x]/!x}8
```

**Upd3:** add [8 queens](https://q-awe.blogspot.com/2020/05/8-queens_26.html) puzzle to blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just keyword `except`.

How to find it: we know idiomatic `k` construction `@&`, so just search through `.q` namespace for it:

```
q)qfind:{([] q:k;k:.q k:key[.q] where (string value .q) like "*",x,"*")}
q)qfind "@&"
q      k
-----------------------------------
inter  k){x@&x in y}
except k){x@&~x in y}
xcols  k){(x,f@&~(f:cols y)in x)#y}

q) (til 8) except 2 4 6
0 1 3 5 7
```